# Etymology of the Biblical Greek words "sigao" and "sige"

Tags: etymology, greek

Does anyone have any leads as to the etymology of the greek words *sigao* ([strongs # 4601](http://biblesuite.com/greek/4601.htm)) and *sige* (strongs # sige) which are translated *silence* and *silent* respectively in the new testament?

Comment: It comes from PIE *_swī-g-_ 'cease, be silent'; it's cognate also with Modern German _schweigen_, and Old English _swīgan_, with the same meaning. It refers to not speaking, rather than just not making noise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chantraine, [*Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue grecque*](http://archive.org/stream/Dictionnaire-Etymologique-Grec/Chantraiine-DictionnaireEtymologiqueGrec#page/n1019/mode/2up) says the etymology is "obscure" and refers to two hypotheses:

- that it derives from an "expressive syllable" σι-, which I suppose is analogous to English *shh*
- that it derives from a conjectural *swīg-* which is also ancestral to Ger *schweigen*, "to be mute", and goes back to PIE *su̯ī-, -g-, -k-, -p-* (Pokorny 1052), "fade, weaken, etc."

Further references are at the link above. The Pokorny entry is online at [Indo-European Etymological Dictionary](http://dnghu.org/indoeuropean.html).

Comment: The *sw- etymology, however, is difficult ("très douteux" as Chantraine says) because PIE *sw- regularly gives Greek h-, not s-.

Answer (score 3):

IE *sueigh- should become *εἱχ- in Greek. Beekes, Greek Etym. Dictionary, page 1327 suggests that σῖγα is "probably of onomatopoetic origin”.

Comment: Note also *sus*, which is commonly used in the region for *shhh*.  It is commonly thought to be from the Turkish verb *susmak*, but I can't find cognates of it in other Turkic languages, it could be that the verb was the derivation.

Answer (score -1):

To connect the *swig- from old high german swīgān with the greek σιγ- one can suppose the greek interjection (that must be prior to the verb) had a digamma phonem like so *σFιγ-
coming from PIE *su̯ī-g- that disappeared in the early sound history of greek.

Comment: This is a bad hypothesis. Even if the -w- had got lost (for some unexplained reason), the s- would still have become h-, not s-.

Comment: As fdb says, would this make a difference?  Apparently "sweet" and Greek "[hedus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ἡδύς#Ancient_Greek)" are cognate; the digamma originally present in the later didn't preserve the s.